# Acomodo de tabla Sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, tablas

El problema es que tengo una lista en SQlite y la muestro en un array y es alimentada por un servicio eso ya lo hace mi aplicación.

[image: Es como actualmente lo muestro en mi aplicación]

Pero ahora me piden que el acomodo sea diferente, me piden que la primera posición de mi tabla se muestre en el ultimo lugar como se ve en la imagen que dibuje.

[image: Dejo un boceto de como quieren que se muestre]

```
public List<ModeloReparto>obtenerRepartos(){
    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getDetalleTravel();
    Repartos = new ArrayList<>();
        if (data.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Repartos.add(new ModeloReparto(data.getString(1),data.getString(2),data.getString(4),data.getString(3),data.getString(5),data.getString(6),data.getString(7),data.getString(8),data.getString(9),data.getString(0)));
        }while (data.moveToNext());

    }

    return Repartos;

}
```

y así obtengo la información del servicio

```
try{
    JSONArray repartos = travel.getJSONArray(REPARTOS);
    for (int i = 0; i < repartos.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject itemReparto = repartos.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject reparto = itemReparto.getJSONObject("Reparto");
        int LlegaCteFecR = reparto.getInt("LlegaCteFecR");
        int LlegaCteHorR = reparto.getInt("LlegaCteHorR");
        int CargaFecIniR = reparto.getInt("CargaFecIniR");
        int CargaHorIniR = reparto.getInt("CargaHorIniR");
        int CargaFecFinR = reparto.getInt("CargaFecFinR");
        int CargaHorFinR = reparto.getInt("CargaHorFinR");
         int SalidCteFecR = reparto.getInt("SalidCteFecR");
        int SalidCteHorR = reparto.getInt("SalidCteHorR");
        int LlegaCteDesFecR = reparto.getInt("LlegaCteDesFecR");
        int LlegaCteDesHorR = reparto.getInt("LlegaCteDesHorR");
        int DescFecIniR = reparto.getInt("DescFecIniR");
        int DescHorIniR = reparto.getInt("DescHorIniR");
        int DescFecFinR = reparto.getInt("DescFecFinR");
        int DescHorFinR = reparto.getInt("DescHorFinR");
        int SalidCteDesFecR = reparto.getInt("SalidCteDesFecR");
        int SalidCteDesHorR = reparto.getInt("SalidCteDesHorR");
        //int LlegaCteFecP = reparto.getInt("LlegaCteFecP");
        //int LlegaCteHorP = reparto.getInt("LlegaCteHorP");
        //int DescFecIniP = reparto.getInt("DescFecIniP");
        //int DescHorIniP = reparto.getInt("DescHorIniP");
        String CartaPorte = reparto.getString("CartaPorte");
        Cliente = reparto.getString("Cliente");
        String PoblacionOri = reparto.getString("PoblacionOri");
        String CalleOri = reparto.getString("CalleOri");
        String Calle = reparto.getString("Calle");
        String RepartoPedido = reparto.getString("Pedido");
        String DescFecIniPlan = reparto.getString("DescFecIniP");
        String DescHorIniPlan = reparto.getString("DescHorIniP");
        String DescFecFinPlan = reparto.getString("DescFecFinP");
        String DescHorFinPlan = reparto.getString("DescHorFinP");
        String LlegaCteFecPlan = reparto.getString("LlegaCteFecP");
        String LlegaCteHorPlan = reparto.getString("LlegaCteHorP");
        String SalidCteFecPlan = reparto.getString("SalidCteFecP");
        String SalidCteHorPlan = reparto.getString("SalidCteHorP");
        Direccion = PoblacionOri+" "+CalleOri+" "+Calle;
        HorarioPlaneado =" Hora: " +" "+DescHorIniPlan+ " " + "Fecha: "+" "+DescFecIniPlan ;
        String CartaPortee= "Carta porte: "+CartaPorte;
        LlegadaDesPlan = "Hora: "+" "+LlegaCteHorPlan + "  "+ "Fecha: "+" "+LlegaCteFecPlan;
        DescargaInitPlan = "Hora: "+" "+DescHorIniPlan + "  "+ "Fecha: "+" "+DescFecIniPlan;
        DescargaFinPlan = "Hora: "+" "+DescHorFinPlan + "  "+ "Fecha: "+" "+DescFecFinPlan;
        DescargaSalidaPlan = "Hora: "+" "+SalidCteHorPlan + "  "+ "Fecha: "+" "+SalidCteFecPlan;
        Log.d(TAG, "==============================");
        Log.d(TAG, "LlegaCteFecR:" + LlegaCteFecR);
        Log.d(TAG, "LlegaCteHorR:" + LlegaCteHorR);
        Log.d(TAG, "CargaFecIniR:" + CargaFecIniR);
        Log.d(TAG, "evidenciaCarta:" + CartaPorte);
        idCartaEvidencias = String.valueOf(CartaPorte);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        mDBHelper.addDetalleTravel(Cliente,Direccion,HorarioPlaneado,RepartoPedido,CartaPorte,
                LlegadaDesPlan, DescargaInitPlan, DescargaFinPlan, DescargaSalidaPlan);
        Log.d(TAG, "addDetalleTravel:" +"cliente:"+Cliente+"Direccion:"+Direccion+
                "FechaPlan:"+HorarioPlaneado+"CartaPorte:"+CartaPorte+ "Pedido:" + RepartoPedido);
        mDBHelper.addTravel(new TravelData(
                LlegaCteFecR, LlegaCteHorR, CargaFecIniR, CargaHorIniR, CargaFecFinR,
                CargaHorFinR, SalidCteFecR, SalidCteHorR, LlegaCteDesFecR, LlegaCteDesHorR,
                DescFecIniR, DescHorIniR, DescFecFinR, DescHorFinR, SalidCteDesFecR,
                SalidCteDesHorR, LlegaCteFecPlan, LlegaCteHorPlan, DescFecIniPlan, DescHorIniPlan,CartaPorte));
        Log.d(TAG, "Viajes:" + reparto);
    }
    }catch (JSONException e){
        JSONObject repartos = travel.getJSONObject(REPARTOS);
        JSONObject reparto = repartos.getJSONObject("Reparto");
        int LlegaCteFecR = reparto.getInt("LlegaCteFecR");
        int LlegaCteHorR = reparto.getInt("LlegaCteHorR");
        int CargaFecIniR = reparto.getInt("CargaFecIniR");
        int CargaHorIniR = reparto.getInt("CargaHorIniR");
        int CargaFecFinR = reparto.getInt("CargaFecFinR");
        int CargaHorFinR = reparto.getInt("CargaHorFinR");
        int SalidCteFecR = reparto.getInt("SalidCteFecR");
        int SalidCteHorR = reparto.getInt("SalidCteHorR");
        int LlegaCteDesFecR = reparto.getInt("LlegaCteDesFecR");
        int LlegaCteDesHorR = reparto.getInt("LlegaCteDesHorR");
        int DescFecIniR = reparto.getInt("DescFecIniR");
        int DescHorIniR = reparto.getInt("DescHorIniR");
        int DescFecFinR = reparto.getInt("DescFecFinR");
        int DescHorFinR = reparto.getInt("DescHorFinR");
        int SalidCteDesFecR = reparto.getInt("SalidCteDesFecR");
        int SalidCteDesHorR = reparto.getInt("SalidCteDesHorR");
        //int LlegaCteFecP = reparto.getInt("LlegaCteFecP");
        //int LlegaCteHorP = reparto.getInt("LlegaCteHorP");
        //int DescFecIniP = reparto.getInt("DescFecIniP");
        //int DescHorIniP = reparto.getInt("DescHorIniP");

        String CartaPorte = reparto.getString("CartaPorte");
        Cliente = reparto.getString("Cliente");
        String PoblacionOri = reparto.getString("PoblacionOri");
        String CalleOri = reparto.getString("CalleOri");
        String Calle = reparto.getString("Calle");
        String RepartoPedido = reparto.getString("Pedido");
        String DescFecIniPlan = reparto.getString("DescFecIniP");
        String DescHorIniPlan = reparto.getString("DescHorIniP");
        String DescFecFinPlan = reparto.getString("DescFecFinP");
        String DescHorFinPlan = reparto.getString("DescHorFinP");
        String LlegaCteFecPlan = reparto.getString("LlegaCteFecP");
        String LlegaCteHorPlan = reparto.getString("LlegaCteHorP");
        String SalidCteFecPlan = reparto.getString("SalidCteFecP");
        String SalidCteHorPlan = reparto.getString("SalidCteHorP");
        Direccion = PoblacionOri+" "+CalleOri+" "+Calle;
        HorarioPlaneado =" Hora: " +" "+DescHorIniPlan+ " " + "Fecha: "+" "+DescFecIniPlan ;
        String CartaPortee= "Carta porte: "+CartaPorte;
        LlegadaDesPlan = "Hora: "+" "+LlegaCteHorPlan + "  "+ "Fecha: "+" "+LlegaCteFecPlan;
        DescargaInitPlan = "Hora: "+" "+DescHorIniPlan + "  "+ "Fecha: "+" "+DescFecIniPlan;
        DescargaFinPlan = "Hora: "+" "+DescHorFinPlan + "  "+ "Fecha: "+" "+DescFecFinPlan;
        DescargaSalidaPlan = "Hora: "+" "+SalidCteHorPlan + "  "+ "Fecha: "+" "+SalidCteFecPlan;
        Log.d(TAG, "==============================");
        Log.d(TAG, "LlegaCteFecR:" + LlegaCteFecR);
        Log.d(TAG, "LlegaCteHorR:" + LlegaCteHorR);
        Log.d(TAG, "CargaFecIniR:" + CargaFecIniR);
        Log.d(TAG, "evidenciaCarta:" + CartaPorte);
        idCartaEvidencias = String.valueOf(CartaPorte);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        mDBHelper.addDetalleTravel(Cliente,Direccion,HorarioPlaneado,RepartoPedido,CartaPorte,
                LlegadaDesPlan, DescargaInitPlan, DescargaFinPlan, DescargaSalidaPlan);
        Log.d(TAG, "addDetalleTravel:" +"cliente:"+Cliente+"Direccion:"+Direccion+
                "FechaPlan:"+HorarioPlaneado+"CartaPorte:"+CartaPorte+ "Pedido:" + RepartoPedido);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas cambiar el acomodo de tus elementos tienes como opción cambiar el orden de la lista mediante

> [Collections.reverse(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) Invierte el orden de los elementos en la
>   lista especificada.

Por ejemplo te sugiero que tu método reciba un boolean que determine si deseas la lista ordenada normal o invertida:

```
public List<ModeloReparto>obtenerRepartos(boolean invertida){
    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getDetalleTravel();
    Repartos = new ArrayList<>();
        if (data.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Repartos.add(new ModeloReparto(data.getString(1),data.getString(2),data.getString(4),data.getString(3),data.getString(5),data.getString(6),data.getString(7),data.getString(8),data.getString(9),data.getString(0)));
        }while (data.moveToNext());

    }

      //Invierte el orden de los datos.
      if(invertida){ 
          Collections.reverse(Repartos)
      }

    return Repartos;

}
```

Comment: Implemente tu respuesta pero solamente me acomoda a la inversa
123 ==>321 y lo que ando buscando es este orden 123 ==>231

Comment: @GiovanniAntonioCarrilloMuji para obtener el orden 231 lo realizarías en base que valor del objeto?

Comment: el valor del objeto lo puedo agarar     public static final String COLUMNA_ID_RECORD = "ID"; o del campo llamado cartaporte que trae el servicio